# StringBuilder used multiple times doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

I have a problem with StringBuilder which doesn't work properly when used multiple times. Here is an example where I make string from byte array of hash.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

//MD5
MD5 Md5 = MD5.Create();
foreach (byte b in Md5.ComputeHash(exeStream))
    stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);

CompareHashValueMd5 = stringBuilder.ToString().ToLower();
stringBuilder.Clear();


// SHA1
SHA1Managed SHhash = new SHA1Managed();
foreach (byte b in SHhash.ComputeHash(exeStream))
    stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);

CompareHashValueSha = stringBuilder.ToString().ToLower();
stringBuilder.Clear();

// SHA256    
SHA256Managed SHhash256 = new SHA256Managed();
foreach (byte b in SHhash256.ComputeHash(exeStream))
    stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);

CompareHashValueSha256 = stringBuilder.ToString().ToLower();
stringBuilder.Clear();
```

The results are:

MD5: CORRECT

SHA1: INCORRECT

SHA256: INCORRECT

When I remove the MD5 and run the program again the SHA1 is fine but the SHA256 is not. So I guess the problem is with reusing of the stringBuilder. Any idea what to do with this? Thanks

Comment: Heck, the solution is even right there in the [example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa627k19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the `StringBuilder` reuse which is the problem, it's the repeated use of the same `Stream` without rewinding it.

Save the `Position` property before each hash calculation and set it back before the next one.